# Move files from one folder to multiple folders based on filename using SSIS expression task and File system task

Tags: ssis

I have a scenario where i need to move files from one folder to different folders based on filename.

Example : In the main folder i have files with different names, All Files which contain specific name in the file name should go into different folders.

i created a expression task and File system task to achieve the same, but all the files in main folder are getting deleted but are not available in respective folders.

This is the expression i am using in expression task based on which i a setting the destination folder.

```
!(ISNULL( FINDSTRING( @[User::FileName] , @[User::FileV2] , 1 ) )) ?    @[User::DestinationFolder] == @[User::Folder1] : !(ISNULL( FINDSTRING( @[User::FileName] , @[User::FileV3] , 1 ) ) )?    @[User::DestinationFolder] == @[User::Folder2] :!(ISNULL( FINDSTRING( @[User::FileName] ,  @[User::FilePlacement] , 1 ) )) ?    @[User::DestinationFolder] ==  @[User::Folder3] :  @[User::DestinationFolder] ==  @[User::Folder3]
```

Let me know how this can done.

Answer (score 0):

Findstring returns NULL only if search string or expression are null, in the case you are showing most likely returns 0 when not found and therefore ISNULL will always returns FALSE.

I suggest to use >0 to test the conditions, something like:

```
FINDSTRING( @[User::FileName] , @[User::FileV2] , 1 ) > 0 ...
```